# Siemens S7: get TIA project name @runtime

Tags: plc

**Question**

Is it possible to get the TIA Portal `project name` or the `project version` or at least any `metadata` about the project from inside the PLC program at runtime as `String`? Getting the information at compile time as a constant would help too.

**Background**

The project contains a lot of (around 20) Siemens S7 CPUs with the same source code. All the CPUs are connected to an `OPC UA` Server. I would like to have a way to manage different source code versions by providing the versions as an `OPC UA item`.

**Environment**

TIA Portal: v14 SP1 Update 1
PLC: CPU 1510SP F-1 PN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution to this problem is to use the function `GetChecksum`. It reads out the checksum of the program that is currently on the PLC as `byte array` (8 bytes). The checksum then can be compared to the one in the properties of the PLC in the TIA project.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to KasparJohannes' solution is to add a data block that stores the project data as a string. For each project version, you would need to update this data.

It would be easily accessible from OPC UA since the data is stored in a data block.

[image: Screenshot of a possible solution in TIA Portal]

Comment: Thanks, I think at the time I needed something foolproof. We had no access to the PLCs remotely, however, we could connect to the OPC Server. The project name always included the version code for the program and one could rely on this information to be correct. However, using a variable that would have to be set by the programmer, one could never be 100% sure that this information is correct or if the programmer simply forgot to update the variable...